# cakephp3 デバッグツール

Tags: php, cakephp

visual studioのような、cakephp3 でおすすめのデバッグツールがあれば教えて下さい。
例えばブレークポイントを設定して、そのときに格納されている変数の中身を簡単にみたいです。（JavaScript側、php側で）
Atomを使ってますが、そのような機能も使えるのでしょうか。
今は、phpはdebug.logに出力、JavaScriptはconsole.log出力にて確認している状況です。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　このサイトでは、人によって意見がバラバラになりそうな、主観的な回答しかつきそうにない質問は好まれません。「Visual Studio のような」とおっしゃいますが、具体的に Visual Stuio のどのような機能が欲しいのか列挙して頂けませんか？　質問文の下の「編集」から自由に編集できますので、そこから追記してください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。初めてなもので、このようなアドバイスは非常に助かります。

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP は PHP なので、Xdebug の利用が可能です。

Atom、VSCode、PhpStorm といったメジャーどころのエディタでは、Xdebugに対応しています。

適切に設定すると、Webサーバから開発マシンへ通信が行われ、典型的なブレークポイント・ステップ実行・再続行・変数の閲覧と改ざんが可能になります。

なお、CakePHP 3.4.x 系の一部のバージョンで特定の処理を行った場合、Ajaxなどで頻繁にサーバーにリクエストを発行するプロジェクトでは、うまくデバッグできない場合がありますので、ご注意ください。

1. 仮想マシンを立てて環境構築
   例えばVirtualBox上のブリッジ接続で構築したCentOSのLAMPなど
2. 仮想マシンにxdebug拡張と、対応するphp.iniを設定する
   例：php7.0、remi経由

   ```
   $ yum -y install --enablerepo=remi-php70 php-devel php-pecl-xdebug
   ```

   例：php.dフォルダを参照している場合。直接php.iniに記述してもOK

   ```
   $ sudo vi /etc/php.d/15-xdebug.ini
   ```

   ```
   [xdebug]
   xdebug.default_enable = 1
   xdebug.idekey = "vscode"
   xdebug.remote_enable = 1
   xdebug.remote_port=9000
   xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
   xdebug.remote_host=<開発マシン(ホストマシン)のIP>
   ```
3. Apache再起動

   ```
   $ sudo systemctl restart httpd.service
   ```
4. エディタ側の設定を適切し、エディタのデバッグ開始（xdebug通信を待ち受ける）

   例：Visual Studio codeの場合

   launch.json

   ```
   {
       "version": "0.2.0",
       "configurations": [
           {
               "name": "Listen for XDebug",
               "type": "php",
               "request": "launch",
               "port": 9000,
               "serverSourceRoot": "/var/www/html/<AppRoot>",
               "localSourceRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```